# Can $\chi^2$-test be used to compare two densities?

Tags: chi-squared-test

Can $\chi^2$-test be used to compare two densities?

For example count of something per 5000 meters: like 2050 counts/5000 meters and 1500 counts/5000 meters.

Can $\chi^2$-test be used to see if these two densities are significantly different? I know $\chi^2$-test is used to compare two proportions but not sure if it can work here.

Comment: You can discretize your density, and then use a histogram to estimate the proportions you should get. You can then treat the different intervals as categories whose expected outcome is determined by the percentage in each histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly indirectly, yes.

[I'd probably have called those intensities or rates; calling them 'densities' without some modifying adjective or similar, such as a noun taking the role of an adjective, will tend to lead to confusion with probability densities in a discussion such as this one. It took me a while to realize you weren't asking about comparing probability densities.]

If the counts occur independently and in proportion to the length in meters (as they would if the densities of the events were the same), then yes. Indeed the length in meters don't have to be the same, even though they are in your example.

If the rate per meter is the same (as would be assumed under H0) then you can treat the whole set as two draws from the same population, which should occur in the ratio of the proportions of the lengths in meters to the whole length. In this case, on average both counts should be $\frac{5000}{5000+5000} = \frac12$ the total.

The most common approach would then be to condition on the total and test for equality of proportions; this is equivalent to testing whether the first proportion is one half. Which can indeed be done as a chi-squared goodness of fit test if the sample size is not too small (it's fine in this case).

Note that your expected counts in this case are both $(2050+1500)\times\frac{5000}{5000+5000} $

There's other approaches to arrive at essentially the same test.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure, 2050:5000 and 1500:5000 can be considered as two proportions and we can compare these two like we compare any two proportions in χ2
-test?

Comment: No. Those aren't proportions, but rates.You might make a Poisson process assumption and do a Poisson test if you want it directly in terms of the rate comparison. The sample proportions are 2050/(2050+1500) and 1500/(2050+1500)